# Vertical separation between text and first item inside nodes not consistent

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, nodes, itemize

The appended code yield the following slide.

[image]

Although the code of the four rectangular nodes equals each other the vertical separation between the text and the first item within the rectangle is smaller in `Testbox 1` than in the other boxes. After spending a lot of time to isolate the mistake my tired eyes need finally some help.

---

```
\documentclass[
    handout
]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
   X/.style={rounded corners=5pt, line width=0.75pt, 
             rectangle,text width=4.5cm, align=left, 
             minimum height=3cm,draw},
   T/.style={font=\small,text width=4.5cm,anchor=north west}
}

\newcommand\XBox[1]{%
   \node[X, 
         append after command={
            node[T] at (\tikzlastnode.north west) {%
               #1
            }
         }
   ] {}; 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test slide}
   \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}

         \matrix[column sep=0.5cm, row sep=0.5cm, ampersand replacement=\&]{%
            \uncover<2->{%
               \XBox{%
                  Testbox 1
                  \begin{itemize}
                     \item Test 1
                  \end{itemize}
               }
            }
            \& 
            \uncover<3->{%
               \XBox{%
                  Testbox 2
                  \begin{itemize}
                     \item Test 2
                  \end{itemize}
               }
            }
            \\
            \uncover<5->{%
               \XBox{%
                  Testbox 4
                  \begin{itemize}
                     \item Test 4
                  \end{itemize}
               }
            }
            \& 
            \uncover<4->{%
               \XBox{%
                  Testbox 3
                  \begin{itemize}
                     \item Test 3
                  \end{itemize}
               }
            }
            \\
         };
      \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of doubt, use `\leavevmode` :)

```
\documentclass[
    handout
]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{
   X/.style={rounded corners=5pt, line width=0.75pt, 
             rectangle,text width=4.5cm, align=left, 
             minimum height=3cm,draw},
   T/.style={font=\small,text width=4.5cm,anchor=north west}
}

\newcommand\XBox[1]{%
   \node[X, 
         append after command={
            node[T] at (\tikzlastnode.north west) {%
               #1%
            }%
         }%
   ] {}; 
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test slide}
   \begin{center}\leavevmode
      \begin{tikzpicture}

         \matrix[column sep=0.5cm, row sep=0.5cm, ampersand replacement=\&]{%
            \uncover<2->{%
               \XBox{%
                  Testbox 1%
                  \begin{itemize}
                     \item Test 1
                  \end{itemize}
               }
            }
            \& 
            \uncover<3->{%
               \XBox{%
                  Testbox 2
                  \begin{itemize}
                     \item Test 2
                  \end{itemize}
               }
            }
            \\
            \uncover<5->{%
               \XBox{%
                  Testbox 4
                  \begin{itemize}
                     \item Test 4
                  \end{itemize}
               }
            }
            \& 
            \uncover<4->{%
               \XBox{%
                  Testbox 3
                  \begin{itemize}
                     \item Test 3
                  \end{itemize}
               }
            }
            \\
         };
      \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your help! You TeX giants (10k+) really amaze me!